# Why are Robb's last words "Jeyne? Mother... Grey Wind"?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In **aSoS, Catelyn VII**, Catelyn begs Walder Frey to let her injured son go and keep her and Edmure as hostages in his stead. Robb refuses:

> "No." Robb's voice was whisper faint. "Mother, no..."
>
> "Yes. Robb, get up. Get up and walk out, please, *please*. Save yourself... if not for me, for Jeyne."
>
> "Jeyne?" Robb grabbed the edge of the table and forced himself to stand. **"Mother," he said, "Grey Wind..."**
>
> "Go to him. Now. Robb, *walk out of here*."

Of course, Lord Walder won't let him do that and we all know what happens, but I find Robb's last words curious. Why did he think of Grey Wind when she mentioned Jeyne? I don't see the connection there. And what did he want to say about Grey Wind?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A common theory is that Robb says Grey Wind's name because **he's about to warg into him**. Just as Bran learned how to warg into Summer, perhaps Robb had learned how to warg into *his* direwolf. Knowing that he was about to die, he might have warged into Grey Wolf in a desperate attempt to keep at least some part of himself alive - an attempt which was, of course, tragically futile, since Grey Wolf was also killed at around the same time. If this theory is correct, then Robb would have died once and then died again shortly afterwards: a sad fate indeed.

Note the connection with Jon Snow's final word in *A Dance with Dragons* being "Ghost".

There doesn't seem to be any canon or Word of God information to either confirm or reject this hypothesis, so it remains simply a theory, and as far as I know, the most likely one anyone has come up with as an explanation for Robb's final words.

Further reading:

- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/1fnk1u/spoilers_asos_did_robb_warg_into_greywind/)
- [AWOIAF forums](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/87861-robbs-last-wordsdwd-spoilers/)
- [AWOIAF forums](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/87919-did-robb-stark-warg-into-grey-wind-as-he-died/)
- [a Tumblr page](http://nobodysuspectsthebutterfly.tumblr.com/post/71269920977/why-was-robbs-last-words-greywind)

Comment: +1. Nice hypothesis but I think him warging into Greywind _intentionally_ is a bit too much. Bran had training. Jon and Arya however show us that it is possible for wargs to do it without intention. So it maybe possible that Robb was sliding towards Greywind but not intentionally, maybe a survival instinct was guiding him.

Comment: As for "Jeyne?", I suspect given his injuries and massive blood loss, he was struggling to understand what his mother had said about Jeyne. An alternate hypothesis would be that Robb realized he was done for and he was trying to tell his mother to save Greywind. Or maybe as you said, he was sliding into the wolf and felt his presence.